# Need to make particular corner round of view

Tags: ios, swift

**I want my UIView round from top right and top left only**

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

Comment: specify the iOS version being targeted, for iOS 11 n above, it can be as straight forward as `view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension of UIView

```
extension UIView{

 func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
         let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
         let mask = CAShapeLayer()
         mask.path = path.cgPath
         layer.mask = mask
     }
}
```

call function for your view

```
topView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 8)
```